# Equality in Distribution for Suprema of Uncountably Many Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables

According to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2563869/602889), if $(X_t)_{t\in T}$ and $(Y_t)_{t\in T}$ are equal in distribution and if $T$ is countable, then their suprema $\sup_{t\in T}X_t$ and $\sup_{t\in T}Y_t$ are equal in distribution. I wonder if the conclusion still holds when $T$ is uncountable (assuming the suprema are measurable)?

Comment: Yes, provided you have say continuity, otherwise you can not even make sense of the uncountable supremum!

Comment: You should first ask if the suprema are random variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other pointed out in the comments there's no guarantee the suprema are random variables, however, even they are the statement is not true.

For $t \in  [0,1]$ take

$$ 
X_{t}(\omega) = \begin{cases}
t &\text{$\omega = t$}\\
0 &\text{every other case}
\end{cases}
$$

in the probability spaces $([0,1],\mathfrak{B},\mathcal{L})$ where $\mathcal{L}$ is the Lebesgue measure. The process $(X_{t})$ has the same distribution as the process $(Y_{t})$ where $Y_{t}(w)=0$ (all the random variables are 0 a.s. in both cases). The suprema for the first process is a random variable with uniform distribution and for the second process the suprema is 0 (a.s. and otherwise).

Comment: Here I think you are using "equal in distribution" to mean that for every finite collection of samples times $(t_1, ..., t_n)$, the random vector $(X(t_1), ..., X(t_n))$ has the same distribution as $(Y(t_1), ..., Y(t_n))$.

Comment: Ah yes, I was using the same definiton as the response in the linked post.